# Python escape file path for command line command

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am trying to send a shell command via python which contains a file path. The command would be like:

> omxplayer "/media/drive/Cool Videos!/showfilename.avi"

and I am sending it like so:

```
Popen(['omxplayer '+filePath], shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True)
```

Now, this normally will work but in this case, the "!" in the folder name causes a bash error.

How can I escape the entire file path? I tried putting it in quotes which worked for most things except for exclamation marks (and maybe other characters that I am not aware of).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Popen(['omxplayer', unquotedFilePath], shell=False, ...)
```

Comment: This worked. I had tried the ['omxplayer', filePath] before but never with shell=False. The shell=False did the trick!

Comment: Usually that's the best solution, but there are cases where you have to escape the file path anyway. If you need to run a nested command using xdg-su, for instance.